# Why this running code don't print the last value of the string which is /?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, undefined-behavior, strlen

I am using a PATH named ncdir (an extern char pointer) used into others file to read netcdf file.

```
string temp = "/mnt/BIOPHY-RO/Model_AIFS/AIFS_LFN/";
ncdir = (char*) calloc (temp.length(),sizeof(char));
strcpy (ncdir, temp.c_str());
cout<<"last element of the string: "<<ncdir[sizeof(ncdir)]<<endl;
```

I expect the output P instead of N (Last char in the literal string)

Comment: Did you forget to include code?

Comment: what output? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: See please the completed code below

Comment: what is the aim of this exercise? You need to pass a c-string to some legacy API?

Comment: yes, i need to pass the c -string to a function loacted in another file in order to read netcdf files

Comment: @Madiop LO Change the tag from C to C++

Comment: Why dou you need to deal with raw C strings in C++? You'd better use `std::string`. `strcpy` should almost never be used in C++ unless you have a real good reason.

Comment: _"yes, i need to pass the c -string to a function loacted in another file in order to read netcdf files"_: what's the prototype of the function you're mentioning? Believe it or not, the correct answer to your question heavily depends on that.

Comment: @Jabberwocky you well understand the issue; it is used herer sprintf(ncfile, "%s%04d-%02d-%02d.nc",**ncdir**,date->tm_year, date->tm_mon+1, date->tm_mday)

Comment: Instead of `ncdir = (char*) calloc (...` and passing `ncdir` to the function, just pass `temp.c_str()` to the function. Read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)

Comment: it's correct but i get a segment fault, i remembered to have tested this

Comment: _"it's correct but i get a segment fault"_: You need to show more code. Also consider using a debugger, it will help you to find out why the segfault occurs. There are most likely other problems in the code you didn't show in the question. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]. Probabley `ncfile` in `sprintf(ncfile,...` doesn't point to valid memory, What is `ncfile`? How did you declare it? Where does it point?

Comment: Why would you expect the value `P`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky it's declare as follows char ncfile[256]; the type mismatch ?

Comment: @Jabberwocky can you suggest me a debugger which can be used with Makefile please

Comment: Makefiles and debuggers are unrelated. What is your platform/compiler/ide/operating system etc.?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I use pluma editor/command line/Ubuntu

Comment: @MadiopLO sorry I have no idea what pluma is. You probably need the gdb debugger, google `ubuntu pluma gdb` and read the documentation of your platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters you forgot to reserve memory for the terminating zero

```
cdir = (char*) calloc (temp.length(),sizeof(char));
```

And secondly the expression `sizeof(ncdir)` gives the size of the pointer `ncdir` not the size of the pointed array.

Take into account that the last symbol of the string literal is `'/'` bur not `'N'`.

Note:
If actually it is a C++ code then instead of the standard C function `calloc` use the operator `new` to allocate memory.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::string temp = "/mnt/BIOPHY-RO/Model_AIFS/AIFS_LFN/";

    char *ncdir = new char[temp.size() + 1];

    std::strcpy ( ncdir, temp.c_str() );

    std::cout << "last element of the string: " << ncdir[std::strlen( ncdir ) -1] << std::endl;

    delete [] ncdir;
}
```

Its output is

```
last element of the string: /
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, with the new operator i get a core dumped and i don't know the causes. the PATH is one of the arguments of this following c function `sprintf(ncfile, "%s%04d-%02d-%02d.nc",**ncdir**,date->tm_year, date->tm_mon+1, date->tm_mday);`

Comment: @MadiopLO Is it a C++ or C program?

Comment: I both use C and C++ language

Comment: @MadiopLO In C++ there is no such an object as std::cout.:)

Comment: You're right the last element is \ instead of N. With your suggestion (new instance) i get a core dumped in the program. I don't know the causes...

Comment: @MadiopLO The code I showed is correct. The reason of the dump is some other your code that is not shown. Close this your question and open a new one if you want to determine the reason of the dunp.